# How do I expand absolute values?

Tags: analysis, absolute-value

If we have this expression:

$$f = uu-\left( u + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \delta x \right) \left( u + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \delta x \right)$$

we can expand it to this:

$$f = u^2-\left( u^2 + 2u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \delta x + \left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \delta x \right)^2 \right) $$

if we assume that $\delta x$ is very small, then the last term is negligible and the expression becomes simply:

$$f =  - 2u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \delta x$$

Now assume that part of the expression is really an absolute value.  If we return to the original expression, it becomes:

$$f = u|u|-\left( u + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \delta x \right) \left(\bigg| u + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \delta x \bigg| \right)$$

Can this be simplified any further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After consideration I think I understand how to proceed.  We have four different cases:

**Case 1:** $~~u < 0~~$  and  $~~u + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \,\delta x < 0$

**Case 2:** $~~u > 0~~$  and  $~~u + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \,\delta x > 0$

**Case 3:** $~~u < 0~~$  and  $~~u + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \,\delta x > 0$

**Case 4:** $~~u > 0~~$  and  $~~u + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \,\delta x < 0$

If we assume that $u \gg \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \, \delta x$, then we can ignore cases (3) and (4), so:

**Case 1:**

\begin{align}
f_{u<0} & = u (-u) - \left( u + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \, \delta x \right) \left( -u - \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \, \delta x \right) \nonumber \\[1ex]
& = -u^2 - \left( -u^2 - 2\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \, \delta x - \left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \, \delta x \right)^2 \right) \nonumber \\[1ex]
& = 2\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \, \delta x \nonumber
\end{align}

**Case 2:**

\begin{align}
f_{u>0} & = u u - \left( u + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \delta x \right) \left( u + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \, \delta x \right) \nonumber \\[1ex]
& = u^2 - \left( u^2 + 2\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \, \delta x + \left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \, \delta x \right)^2 \right) \nonumber \\[1ex]
& = -2\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \, \delta x \nonumber
\end{align}

These cases can now be combined together:

$$f = \text{sgn}(-u)~2\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \, \delta x$$